# サーバ異なるときの、リダイレクトについての質問です

Tags: nginx

**実現したいこと**

Ａサーバ（メイクショップ）のURLにアクセスしたとき、Ｂサーバ（自社サービス）のURLにリダイレクト処理がかかるようにしたいです

**気になってること**

Ａサーバ（メイクショップ）のURL: http://www.example.jp/html/company.html?code=realisent 
Ｂサーバ（自社サービス）のURL: http://www.example.jp/jp/our-store.html

上記を踏まえて、気になっていることがございます。

Ｂサーバに存在しないコンテンツのＵＲＬ（今回で言えば、http://www.example.jp/html/company.html?code=realisent）をＢサーバ側でリダイレクト処理はできるのでしょうか？

ご教授の程、よろしくお願いします。

**補足情報**

Web Server:  Nginx

Comment: AサーバとBサーバでホスト名が同じになっていますがこれはこの通りなのでしょうか。リダイレクトの起点はAサーバなのかBサーバなのか、質問の冒頭と後段で話が変わっているように思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

リダイレクトはできるけど 404なり403になると思います。

1. クライアントはサーバーAにリクエストを行います。
2. サーバーAは クライアントに対して 30X レスポンスを返します。この際 Location ヘッダで サーバーB のURLを返します。
3. クライアントはLocation ヘッダにしたがってサーバーB のURLにリクエストを行います。
4. サーバーB は 存在しないURLなので 404 403 などの応答を返します。

Comment: ご丁寧に回答して頂きまして、ありがとうございます。

すっきりいたしました。